# LG monitor shuts down after Windows boots up

Tags: monitors, windows, multiple-monitors, vga

I bought an old LG monitor that I wanted to connect with my AMD RX 590. I have another ASUS monitor that works perfectly. The LG monitor has a VGA to display port, and firstly it looks like it works. When I turn the computer the Pro Series shows up on both monitors and a loading. When the loading finishes, so windows is booted up the LG monitor says d-sub no signal entering power saving mode and turns black. When I go on Windows setting it still detects the LG monitor, but I cannot duplicate. Does anybody know how can I fix this issue. The monitor works, and if I try to enter safe mode or the bios it works just fine. When I turn on the PC the loading of windows shows up and when the loading finishes the monitor goes like in stand by, in power saving mode. If I enter in safe mode (shift+f8) I can see windows into the LG monitor but if I go back to the normal windows, nothing doesn't work. So it might be a driver problem. I tried to uninstall both the monitors from the windows control panel but still nothing fixed. Btw, my VGA to display port is new. Thanks.